# Impact of the response content-type on the exploitability of XSS

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I've come across an API of a web application I'm testing, which reflects with **unescaped**, **unencoded**, **user-controlled** data for some requests. However, the response includes the header `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

The response body is simply a JSON, like the following:

```
{"name":"foo","title":"bar"}
```

I did try to perform a simple XSS (classic `<script>alert(1)</script>`), but the script isn't executed.

```
{"name":"<script>alert(1)</script>","title":"bar"}
```

I've read through this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13821/xss-content-type-application-json), but they do not seem to discuss the impact of the content-type header.
OWASP seems to flag the reponse-type as "good" in [this article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233.1_-_HTML_escape_JSON_values_in_an_HTML_context_and_read_the_data_with_JSON.parse).

My question is if the `Content-Type` header in the response has an impact on the exploitability of XSS and possibly other vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is if the `Content-Type` header in the response has an impact on the exploitability of XSS and possibly other vulnerabilities?

Yes, the content type makes a difference. XSS only applies to documents that are capable of running active (script) content in the first place.

A page with the MIME type `application/json` can't contain active content. To the browser it's just data. The situation would be similar with `text/plain`, `text/javascript`, `image/jpeg`, etc.

XSS would be possible with a MIME type of e.g. `text/html`, `image/svg+xml`, `text/xml` and many others. In some cases, vendor-related types such as `application/x-shockwave-flash` may have an XSS potential, too.